# Poner un máximo de resultados para un bucle WHILE

Tags: php, mysql, bucles, while

Tengo el siguiente bucle while:

```
while ($row_equipos = mysqli_fetch_array($query_equipos)) {
            $nombre = $row_equipos['nombre'];
            $query_miembros = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT COUNT(*) as miembros FROM usuarios WHERE equipo = '$nombre'");
            $row_miembros = mysqli_fetch_array($query_miembros);
            $miembros = $row_miembros['miembros'];
        
        ?>
            <div class="container-equipo">
                <div class="container-1">
                    <a href="equipos.php?nombre=<?php echo "$nombre" ?>"><h2 class="h2-abreviacion"><?php echo $row_equipos['abreviacion']; ?></h2></a>
                </div>
                <div class="container-2">
                    <a href="equipos.php?nombre=<?php echo "$nombre" ?>"><h2 class="h2-nombre"><?php echo "$nombre" ?></h2></a>
                    <h2 class="h2-jugados">Torneos Jugados:<br>
                    <?php echo $row_equipos['torneosJugados']; ?></h2>
                    <h2 class="h2-victorias">Torneos Ganados:<br>
                    <?php echo $row_equipos['victorias']; ?></h2>
                </div>
                <div class="container-3">
                    <?php if ($miembros != '15') { ?>
                    <h2 class="h2-miembros"><?php echo "$miembros" ?>/15</h2>
                    <?php } else { ?>
                    <h2 class="h2-miembros-lleno"><?php echo "$miembros" ?>/15</h2>
                    <?php } ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
```

Los atajos y mejoras de variables (como el $nombre en lugar de $row_equipos) son por razones necesarias, no hace falta que lo corrijan pls.

Basicamente, lo que muestra este bucle son los equipos que registrados en la pagina (para un formulario de busqueda), lo que quiero hacer es que luego de 10/15/20 o hasta 25 cargas, aparezca un boton de "Mostrar mas", con tal de no explotar la pagina al entrar a esta pagina de busqueda, haciendo que cada 15 cargas aparezca este boton, que al presionarlo, muestra 15 cargas mas, y asi hasta el final.

Pense en poner una variable del tipo:

```
$var1 = 1;
while ($var1 < 15) {
     //El codigo aqui
     $cantidad++;
}
//y aqui un boton que pondria la variable "$var1" de nuevo en 0
```

Pero no logre hacerlo funcionar, se que me acerco de alguna manera, pero no se como continuar.

¿Como puedo hacer esto?

Comment: y si lo colocas en la query?? con `limit 15` o con declara fuera del while una variable $cantidad ejemplo `$cantidad=1; while($row.....){ if($cantidad==15) break; //resto de codigo $cantidad++;}` esto haria que al llegar cantidad a 15 entre en el if y aplipe el brea para que  rompa el bucle

Comment: No entendi bien a que te refieres, es decir, lo del limite es posible y mas o menos lo enteindo, pero el resto del codigo con $cantidad++, de que me sirve? es decir, yo al hacer lo de cantidad no logre hacer que funcione, ni que me cargue mas ni nada, solo que me vuelva a cargar los 15 que ya habian cargado antes

Comment: porque al hacer el select con una cantidad solo va a tomar hasta 15, y los demas no, eso quiere decir que no voy a poder cargar mas de 15 resultados, cuando queiro que cada 15 cargas, aparezca el boton, que si se apreta, muestra otras 15

Comment: porque en tu caso pones `while ($var1 < 15)` y aumentas es `$cantidad++` osea que `$var` jamas aumenta y no se porque pondrias la condicion en el while :v no obstante lo que intentas no se puede con php! ya que php es un lenguaje de servidor por ende debes enviar al servidor otra solicitud si quieres volver a cargar otros resultados lo que necesitas es `javascript` y hacer una solicitud `ajax` bueno actualmente [fecth()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Utilizando_Fetch) busca un ejemplo ajax

Comment: genial, me imagine que con js se deberia hacer, pero no estaba seguro, sabes como hacerlo?

Comment: Depende con que trabajaras Silvia si con fetch, jQuery o xmlHttpRequest

Comment: No uso ninguna libreria externa, lo ultimo que utilice fue xmlHttpRequest, pero no tengo problema en aprender a utilizar otro metodo para hacer esto (siempre y cuando no sean librerias externas, no me gustan nada)

Comment: Entonces una buena opción es fetch, es nativa de los navegadores y tiene una sintaxis muy simple

Comment: Pero entonces lo que quieres es una paginación no? Eso lo correcto sería lo que te dice @bryro, usar Limit en la consulta, indicando el número de registros y el desplazamiento. Ya te encargas de cojer el número de página que quieres, y la consulta te devuelve los que necesites.

Comment: El problema es que me dicen la teoria, pero no se como ponerla en practica, parece que lo que dicen tiene sentido, pero yo no estoy muy enterado de todos estos metodos que me djieron, como utilizar fetch, hacer una paginacion del select, etc, ese es mi problema, sino yo ya lo hubiera logrado